# Android Application crashing on Lg G2 but not on other phones

Tags: android, lg

So, I have an aplication that executes asynk task and on post execute it generates a listview.

After the json is recieved the app crashes on a LG G2 but not on other phones.

My Log cat is giving this report:

```
10-09 13:45:47.066: E/Entity Response  :(16241): [{"id":"440","name":"Amici's East Coast Pizzeria","address":"226 Redwood Shores Pkwy, Redwood City, CA","lat":"37.5205","lng":"-122.252","promotype":"0.10","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s1.postimg.org\/526tyzobj\/image.jpg","distance":"62.03","ranking":"6.202501588797353"},{"id":"446","name":"Applewood Pizza 2 Go","address":"1001 El Camino Real, Menlo Park, CA","lat":"37.453","lng":"-122.182","promotype":"0.50","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s27.postimg.org\/yth8q6mb7\/image.jpg","distance":"52.89","ranking":"26.442939242734457"},{"id":"453","name":"Giorgio's","address":"1445 Foxworthy Ave, San Jose, CA","lat":"37.2746","lng":"-121.893","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s10.postimg.org\/lk0r9tbsp\/a_A.jpg","distance":"31.97","ranking":"31.973513511004338"},{"id":"447","name":"Pizza Antica","address":"334 Santana Row # 1065, San Jose, CA","lat":"37.3218","lng":"-121.948","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s11.postimg.org\/gt2rkwr8j\/image.jpg","distance":"36.08","ranking":"36.07806101584471"},{"id":"452","name":"Tony & Alba's Pizza & Pasta","address":"3137 Stevens Creek Blvd, San Jose, CA","lat":"37.3233","lng":"-121.952","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s11.postimg.org\/gt2rkwr8j\/image.jpg","distance":"36.20","ranking":"36.199980176527895"},{"id":"449","name":"House of Pizza","address":"527 S Almaden Ave, San Jose, CA","lat":"37.3264","lng":"-121.888","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s29.postimg.org\/9yarz4nmv\/image.jpg","distance":"37.63","ranking":"37.62658687732519"},{"id":"450","name":"Amici's East Coast Pizzeria","address":"225 W Santa Clara St, San Jose, CA","lat":"37.3347","lng":"-121.894","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s1.postimg.org\/526tyzobj\/image.jpg","distance":"38.38","ranking":"38.38406330985574"},{"id":"309","name":"Round Table Pizza: Sunnyvale-Mary-Central Expy","address":"415 N Mary Ave, Sunnyvale, CA","lat":"37.39","lng":"-122.042","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s1.postimg.org\/526tyzobj\/image.jpg","distance":"43.53","ranking":"43.52522799537428"},{"id":"303","name":"Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too","address":"939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA","lat":"37.3863","lng":"-122.086","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s29.postimg.org\/9yarz4nmv\/image.jpg","distance":"43.62","ranking":"43.62472294523851"},{"id":"305","name":"Kapp's Pizza Bar & Grill","address":"191 Castro St, Mountain View, CA","lat":"37.3939","lng":"-122.079","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s27.postimg.org\/yth8q6mb7\/image.jpg","distance":"44.36","ranking":"44.3553242060947"},{"id":"306","name":"Round Table Pizza: Mountain View","address":"570 N Shoreline Blvd, Mountain View, CA","lat":"37.4027","lng":"-122.079","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s11.postimg.org\/gt2rkwr8j\/image.jpg","distance":"45.32","ranking":"45.32142235623846"},{"id":"308","name":"Oregano's Wood-Fired Pizza","address":"4546 El Camino Real, Los Altos, CA","lat":"37.4017","lng":"-122.115","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s29.postimg.org\/9yarz4nmv\/image.jpg","distance":"45.81","ranking":"45.8134266627868"},{"id":"443","name":"Pizz'a Chicago","address":"4115 El Camino Real, Palo Alto, CA","lat":"37.4141","lng":"-122.126","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s10.postimg.org\/lk0r9tbsp\/a_A.jpg","distance":"47.38","ranking":"47.37868781103179"},{"id":"444","name":"California Pizza Kitchen","address":"531 Cowper St, Palo Alto, CA","lat":"37.4481","lng":"-122.159","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s29.postimg.org\/9yarz4nmv\/image.jpg","distance":"51.78","ranking":"51.77711350584475"},{"id":"441","name":"North Beach Pizza","address":"240 E 3rd Ave, San Mateo, CA","lat":"37.5653","lng":"-122.323","promotype":"1.00","tipo":"Cabeleireiros","foto":"http:\/\/s27.postimg.org\/yth8q6mb7\/image.jpg","distance":"69.05
10-09 13:46:54.676: D/dalvikvm(16241): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 455K, 32% free 17111K/25000K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
10-09 13:46:54.696: I/dalvikvm-heap(16241): Grow heap (frag case) to 28.377MB for 9849616-byte allocation
10-09 13:46:54.816: V/RenderScript(16241): Application requested CPU execution
10-09 13:46:54.826: V/RenderScript(16241): 0x61248f10 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
10-09 13:46:54.836: E/rsC++(16241): RS CPP error: Blur radius out of 0-25 pixel bound
10-09 13:46:54.836: E/rsC++(16241): RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Allocation creation failed
10-09 13:46:54.836: E/rsC++(16241): RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Allocation creation failed
10-09 13:46:54.836: A/libc(16241): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000028 (code=1), thread 16241 

(le.dbjsonstring)
10-09 13:51:59.936: D/HyLog(20453): I : /data/font/config/dfactpre.dat, No such file or directory (2)
10-09 13:52:00.046: D/dalvikvm(20453): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 85K, 16% free 21227K/25000K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
10-09 13:52:00.046: I/dalvikvm-heap(20453): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.101MB for 7441936-byte allocation
10-09 13:52:00.186: D/dalvikvm(20453): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 12% free 28494K/32268K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
10-09 13:52:00.206: I/dalvikvm-heap(20453): Grow heap (frag case) to 49.578MB for 20422912-byte allocation
10-09 13:52:00.406: I/Adreno-EGL(20453): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:385>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
10-09 13:52:00.406: I/Adreno-EGL(20453): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.02
10-09 13:52:00.406: I/Adreno-EGL(20453): Build Date: 01/20/14 Mon
10-09 13:52:00.406: I/Adreno-EGL(20453): Local Branch: PMH2-KK_3.5-RB1-AU61-554722-586267-set2
10-09 13:52:00.406: I/Adreno-EGL(20453): Remote Branch: 
10-09 13:52:00.406: I/Adreno-EGL(20453): Local Patches: 
10-09 13:52:00.406: I/Adreno-EGL(20453): Reconstruct Branch: 
10-09 13:52:00.426: D/OpenGLRenderer(20453): Enabling debug mode 0
10-09 13:52:00.666: I/ActivityManager(20453): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@428d7ac8 time:183390382
```

What can it be?

Comment: Did you try the usual methods like try...catch in your code? I am assuming that it's your application.

Comment: Better you put your complete log cat then only it is able to find the reason for force close or crashing

Comment: Yes it's my application, let me just check it up ( It's a really long app , I'll have to dig that particular class ).

Not using a try catch on post exercute method, added it right now and gives me two extra lines :

10-09 13:44:16.696: D/dalvikvm(14991): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 441K, 23% free 26795K/34620K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
10-09 13:44:16.706: D/dalvikvm(14991): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 18% free 28478K/34620K, paused 12ms, total 12ms

Comment: Edited with the complete log cat!

Comment: whats the ram of the phone? i am thinkking its outerspace or possible resource leak..whats the general idea of your app

Comment: I was actually thinking it was a memory problem but the app runs on a vodafone 752 ( smart 4 mini ). So it should be running on a LG G2

Answer (score 8):

Encountered the issue and I found this post. After experimenting sometime, I found out the exact solution of this problem. Though its very late, but i am posting it here for future help of others.

The problem is self-explanatory.

```
E/rsC++(16241): RS CPP error: Blur radius out of 0-25 pixel bound
```

Setting a `shadowRadius` larger than **25px** on a `View` will crash your app with a segmentation fault. This is due to `RenderScript`, more specifically `ScriptIntrinsicBlur`.

More from here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html#setRadius(float)

So use `shadowRadius` value less than **25px** and the problem will be resolved.

Comment: had a shadow radius of 28dp in a textview hence this issue

Answer (score 2):

So, After a while I found that the problem is on the shadow radius of a textview.

After removing that shaddow it runned great. The strange thing is that the app was running on 3 differente phones and one tablet.

Well, I'll continue my journey through android lolol

Comment: I have this issue exclusively on Samsung devices..